# Different results while inserting into temp table and table variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, temp-tables, table-variable

When I'm using a table variable to store queried result like this:

```
INSERT INTO @sortedArticleIds
    SELECT article_id, NULL AS groupBy
    FROM #articleIds a
    GROUP BY article_id
    ORDER BY MIN(sortBy) DESC;
```

the rows inserted to `@sortedArticleIds` change randomly.

But if I use `#table` like this:

```
INSERT INTO #tmp_table
    SELECT article_id, NULL AS groupBy
    FROM #articleIds a
    GROUP BY article_id
    ORDER BY MIN(sortBy) DESC;
```

the rows inserted to `#tmp_table` are always same.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: What you means by *the rows inserted to @sortedArticleIds change randomly* ?

Comment: when i execute same query again, the records insert to variable changes randomly. but `#articleIds` holds same records.

Comment: The order of the rows inserted is insignificant, Always use order by while fetching results from a table even if the records look like they are already stored in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relational database, your table is a set. It means that the `ORDER BY` and your `GROUP BY` of you insert is not needed.

```
INSERT INTO @sortedArticleIds
SELECT article_id, NULL AS groupBy
FROM #articleIds
```

Here you are updating a table, so we don't need an `ORDER BY` clause.

But when you will query your table, prefer a query like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM @sortedArticleIds
GROUP BY article_id
ORDER BY MIN(sortBy) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but when i use #table this returns same results. is there any deference using table variable vs #table in above case.

Comment: You can enable statistics before the query to check if there is a difference.